# xmlHttp to download file

Tags: vba, http-headers, download, xmlhttprequest

Using google chrome i fill in a form and upon pressing the submit button a spreadhsheet automatically starts downloading. I have identified the POST sent to the server but somehow when i send the same request from my script the response is not a file but the original web form. Please see below the request as shown in Chrome :

---

Remote Address: ********** -- Request URL:******* --

Request Method: POST -- Status Code: 200 OK --**

Request Headers

```
-Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
-Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
-Cache-Control:max-age=0
-Connection:keep-alive
-Content-Length:207
-Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
-Cookie:JSESSIONID=*******; ssoLang=en
-Host:*******
-Origin:******
-Referer:*******
-User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

Query String Parameters

Form Data :  *REQUEST*

Response Headers

```
-Content-Disposition: filename="xxx.xlsx"
-Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
-Date:Sat, 31 May 2014 14:28:25 GMT
-Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1 
-Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

---

The response headers I am getting are different :

```
-Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
-Date: Sat, 31 May 2014 14:55:38 GMT
-Pragma: no-cache Transfer-Encoding: chunked
-Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
-Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

---

The script i attempted to do the above is below, can anybody please point out what is wrong here ?

```
Sub Download_File()
    Dim localFile As String, URL As String, request As String
    localFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsx"
    URL = ****SENSITIVE***
    Dim XMLreq As Object
    Set XMLreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    request = ****REQUEST*****


    Dim fileNum As Integer, bytes() As Byte
    With XMLreq
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Host", ****SENSITIVE***
        .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "207"
        .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
        .setRequestHeader "Origin", ****SENSITIVE***
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", ****SENSITIVE***
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
        .setRequestHeader "Cookie", "JSESSIONID=****SENSITIVE***; ssoLang=en"
        .send (Escape(request))
    While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    If .Status = 200 Then
        Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
        fileNum = FreeFile
        Open localFile For Binary Access Write As #fileNum
        bytes = .responseBody
        Put #fileNum, , bytes
        Close #fileNum
    Else
        MsgBox "XMLhttp POST error " & .statusText & vbCrLf & "Status = " & .Status & vbCrLf & "URL = " & URL
    End If
    End With
End Sub


Private Function Escape(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer, BadChars As String
    BadChars = "<>%=&!@#£$^()+{[}]|\;:'"",/?"
    For i = 1 To Len(BadChars)
        URL = Replace(URL, Mid(BadChars, i, 1), "%" & Hex(Asc(Mid(BadChars, i, 1))))
    Next i
    URL = Replace(URL, " ", "+")
    Escape = URL
End Function
```

Comment: Installing *Fiddler* will enable you to compare the two requests in their raw form and look for differences

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will install it on my home computer. The problem is i am not allowed to install this at work so would have to diagnose the request with something else for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but more like a comment. I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment.

The response looks like you are redirected to the web form when some checks or authentication fails. Did you check the JSESSIONID cookie? That should be different for each time you logon to the server. Once you manually login and then capture the JSESSIONID cookie (either using Fiddler as Alex mentioned) or by typing `javascript:alert(document.cookie);` in the browser address bar and pressing enter, you might be able to reuse the same session token.

Also check the content length to ensure that the url-encoded content length matches this value. You can use the composer feature in Fiddler to test POST queries to the server to get the request parameters correct.

BTW, Fiddler installation folder can be copied to a USB stick and used as a portable installation. You might try that as well.

**Edit**: Looking further, the issue seems to be that the site requires a correct Referer header for sending out the excel file. As unsafe headers like Referer cannot be set for XMLHttp request, this might cause server side authentication failure and it might send you the initial landing page which is the web form here. Check this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218525/set-referer-for-xml-http-request)