# Set referer for XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am successfully sending a `XMLHttpRequest` by using:

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Most browsers.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // IE8 & IE9
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};

var url = 'http://www.whatismyip.com';
var method = 'GET';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  // Success code goes here.
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  // Error code goes here.
};


xhr.setRequestHeader('referer', 'http://www.google.com');
xhr.send();
```

However, I could not able to define my `referer`. What is the correct way to add the custom `referer`?

Comment: I have same problem and could not understand why XMLHttpRequest does not have referrer or User-Agent informations? Is there any way to catch them all using fetch or axios?

Answer (score 19):

You cannot. The [XMLHttpRequest specification forbids](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) the altering of the `referer` header (this stops sites lying in it to bypass security checks which some sites use the referer for).

> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
> - …
> - Referer
> - …

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Referer', window.location.href);
```

And then read this custom *X-Referer* header.

Answer (score -2):

Answer found on https://www.trustedsec.com/blog/setting-the-referer-header-using-javascript/

You can set it using `window.history.replaceState(null, '', 'https://yourwebsite.com/forged/referer')`

As far as I know it only works with the same domain, but you can forge the path this way.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState