# how to verify referrer inside a MVC or Web Api ajax call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, csrf

my MVC app has common ajax methods (in web api and regular controller). I'd like to authorize these calls based on which area (view) of my app the call is coming from. The problem I am facing is how to verify the origin of the ajax call.

I realize that this is not easily possible since ajax calls are easy to spoof, but since I have full control of how the view gets rendered (full page source) perhaps there is a way to embed anti-forgery type tokens that could later be verified to a Url Referrer.

Authentication is already handled and I can safely verify the identity of the call, the only problem is verifying which URL (MVC route) the call came from. More specifically, preventing the user from being able to spoof the origin of the ajax call.

I tried creating a custom authorization header and passing it between view render and ajax calls, and that works, but still easy to spoof (since a user could sniff the headers from another part of the site and re-use those). In the end I am not sure how to safely verify that the header has not been spoofed. The only thing that comes to mind is encoding some info about the original context inside the token, and validating it somehow against incoming call context (the one that's passing the token in ajax call).

I see that MVC has AntiForgery token capabilities, but I am not sure if that can solve my problem. If so I'd like to know how it could be used to verify that `/api/common/update` was called from `/home/index` vs `/user/setup` (both of these calls are valid).

Again, i'd like a way to verify which page an ajax call is coming from, and user identity is not the issue.

**update**

as per @Sarathy recommended I tried implementing anti-forgery token. As far as I can tell this works by adding a hidden field with token on each page, and comparing it to a token set in a cookie. Here is my implementation of custom action filter attribute that does token validation:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var fToken = req.Headers["X-Request-Verification-Token"];
        var cookie = req.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        var cToken = cookie != null
            ? cookie.Value
            : "null";

        log.Info("filter \ntoken:{0} \ncookie:{1}", fToken, cToken);
        AntiForgery.Validate(cToken, fToken);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

then my anti forgery additional data provider looks like this:

```
public class MyAntiForgeryProvider : IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider
{
    public string GetAdditionalData(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var ad  = string.Format("{0}-{1}",context.Request.Url, new Random().Next(9999));
        log.Info("antiforgery AntiForgeryProvider.GetAdditionalData Request.AdditionalData: {0}", ad);
        log.Info("antiforgery AntiForgeryProvider.GetAdditionalData Request.UrlReferrer: {0}", context.Request.UrlReferrer);
        return ad;
    }

    public bool ValidateAdditionalData(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, string additionalData)
    {
        log.Info("antiforgery AntiForgeryProvider.ValidateAdditionalData Request.Url: {0}", context.Request.Url);
        log.Info("antiforgery AntiForgeryProvider.ValidateAdditionalData additionalData: {0}", additionalData);
        return true;
    }
```

this works, in that i can see correct pages logged in the provider, and anti forgery breaks w/out the tokens.

however, unless i did something wrong, this seems trivial to spoof. for example 
if i go to pageA and copy the token form pageB (just the form token, not even the cookie token), this still succeeds, and in my logs i see pageB while executing ajax method from pageA

**confirmed that this is pretty easy to spoof**.

I am using csrf to generate ajax tokens like this:

```
    public static string MyForgeryToken(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var c = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(c != null ? c.Value : null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return formToken;
    }
```

I then pass the form token back with each ajax call and have a custom actionfilterattribute where I read/validate it along with cookie token

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var fToken = req.Headers[GlobalConstants.AntiForgeKey];
        var cookie = req.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        var cToken = cookie != null
            ? cookie.Value
            : "null";


        log.Info("MyAntiForgeryAttribute.OnActionExecuting. \ntoken:{0} \ncookie:{1}", fToken, cToken);
        AntiForgery.Validate(cToken, fToken);
```

this all works (changing anything about the token throws correct exception), then in my IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider I can see what it thinks it's processing.

as soon as i override the csrf token from another view, it thinks it's that view. I don't even have to tamper with the UrlReferrer to break this :/

**one way this could work if i could force the cookie to be different on every page load**

Comment: Classic XY problem...

Comment: @DavidPeden i've outlined my problem and am open to ideas on how to solve it differently. I've also outlined possible other solutions I am trying to avoid. that said, your comment is not very constructive

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I posted that not to be snarky but rather to give any other person interested enough in reading your question the opportunity to consider that what you're asking is not what you really mean (as explicitly discussed on @eol's assumptions and your subsequent comments). I happen to agree with his generic advice even though you are trying to avoid it. It looks like you have painted yourself into a corner with some basic assumptions that I think should be challenged. If it is cost-prohibitive to do so, I understand completely and have no further advice.

Comment: ok thanks. yeah it's totally possible I am going down a dead end, but that's why I posted on here to verify I am not missing something in my approach. It has been a very educational experience never the less ;)

Comment: Was reconsidering this, and had this thought: Even if you can verify that the ajax request came from your source page, what's to stop the malicious user from live editing your JavaScript on that page to call a different api (or same api with different parameters)?  I think you're assuming that if the request came from your page the request itself must be allowed, since you wrote the JavaScript on that page...but I don't think that's a valid assumption.

Comment: authorization happens on the server. it doesn't matter what parameters are forged or which method was redirected to, as long as i know who it is, and where the call is coming from i can assess the access. i don't rely on anything in javascript

Answer (score 1):

My quick interim solution was to use custom tokens created on each page load (guid which i keep track of in my token cache), which are passed as headers in all ajax calls. Additionally i create a original url hash and combine it into the custom auth token. 
in my ajax methods I then extract the hash and compare it with UrlReferrer hash to ensure that hasn't been tampered with. 
since the custom token is always different it's less obvious to guess what's going on as token appears to be different on every page load. however this is not secure because with enough effort the url hash can be uncovered. The exposure is somewhat limited because user identity is not the problem so worst case is a given user would gain write access to another section of the site but only as himself. My site is internal and i am auditing every move so any temper attempts would be caught quickly.

I am using both jQuery and angular so appending tokens with all requests like this:

```
var __key = '@Html.GetHeaderKey()' //helper method to get key from http header
//jQuery
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Nothing-To-See-Here', __key); // totally inconspicuous 
})

//angular
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Nothing-To-See-Here'] = __key;
});
```

**update**

the downside of this approach is that custom tokens need to be persisted across a web farm or app restarts. Based on @Sarathy's idea I am trying to side step this by leveraging MVC anti forgery framework. Basically add/remove my "salt" and let the framework manage the actual token validation. That way it's a bit less to manage for me. Will post more details once i verify that this is working.

Comment: I'm curious where the requirement originates. What behavior are you trying to prevent?

Comment: my authorization model is based on each view (MVC Path), and i have common ajax methods that are called from different places within the site. i want to authorize them based on the source view the call came from.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not more helpful.  Is there a reason you wouldn't use the same authorization model on the api controllers as you are using on the mvc controllers.

Comment: np! actually i am using the same model. but this only let's me give a all or nothing access to the web api method. So I can say that user A can or can't access /api/entity/update method. But it doesn't let me declare that access based on where in the site the call is coming from. It would be nice to have that capability in a secure manner.

Comment: another alternative is table level or row level access, but that's a lot of maintenance if you have a 100's of tables, so reserving that only for select few tables..

Comment: What if you Encrypt your hash and custom auth token and decrypt it in your ajax response method?

Comment: sure but those same tokens can be copied and passed from another view ;)

Comment: @SonicSoul - Why would you assume the authorize attribute gives you all or nothing access? You can specify roles. You can also customize the attribute(s) for tighter access if you need to.

Comment: @NightOwl888 that's not what i meant. 
I mean it gives access to a role for an action. No matter how granular the access is. 
In my model, I am looking to give access based on the page the call is coming from, not just who is executing the action (which is also implemented)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you can use IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider for this.

```
public class CustomDataProvider : IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider
{
   public string GetAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context)
   {
     // Return the current request url or build a route or create a hash from a set of items from the current context.
     return context.Request.Url.ToString();
    }

    public bool ValidateAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context, string additionalData)
    {
       // Check whether the allowed list contains additional data or delegate the validation to a separate component.
       return false;
     }
}
```

Register the provider in App_Start like below.

```
AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider = new CustomDataProvider();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.iantiforgeryadditionaldataprovider(v=vs.111).aspx

Hope this helps in your scenario.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this and will add an update on my question with my results (too long to list here)

Comment: Did you try comparing the additional data with the header "Referer"? If they both are different, then the request is spoofed.

Comment: yeah but referrer is just as easy to spoof .. it's just a httpHeader. 

my currently solution is using a custom token + referrer hash so it's not as obvious, but still easy to spoof once you know how it works

Comment: Yes, but browsers do not allow anyone to set the "Referer" header as per the accepted answer in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218525/set-referer-for-xml-http-request

Comment: hmm, if referrer was not spoofable then i wouldn't need any of this token business. all i care about is the origin of the call. it is in fact not impossible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing#Tools

Comment: Yes you are right. You do not need any other mechanism if referer is not spoofable. I guess there is no other way. You have to retrieve some information from the request and compare it on the server. Since all your requests are authenticated, the worst thing that can happen is an authenticated user attempting any spoofing attempts which you should be able to track and block the user.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your question that you're looking for **Anti-forgery token capabilities.**

Hence, I think what you're asking about is an **anti-CSRF solution** (CSRF=cross site request forgery).

One way to do this is to render a **true random number (a one-time token)** into your page, then passing it on each request, which can be done by adding a key/value pair to the request header and then checked at the backend (i.e. inside your controller). This is a **challenge-response** approach.

As you mentioned, in the **server-side code** you can use

```
var fToken = req.Headers["X-Request-Verification-Token"];
```

to get it from the requesting page.

To pass it along from each **client AJAX request** of the page, you can use

```
var tokenValue = '6427083747'; // replace this by rendered random token
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-Request-Verification-Token', tokenValue);
});
```

or you can set it for each request by using

```
var tokenValue = '2347893735'; // replace this by rendered random token
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'X-Request-Verification-Token': tokenValue }
});
```

**Note** that `tokenValue` needs to contain the random number which was rendered by the web server when the web page was sent to the client.

I would not use cookies for this, because cookies don't protect you against CSRF - you need to ensure that the page, which is requesting is the same as the page which was rendered (and hence created by the web server). A page being on a different tab in the same browser window could use the cookie as well.

Details can be found on the [OWASP project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) page, in the [OWASP CSRF prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: I was thinking of something along these lines as well. Additionally, the backend needs to keep track of the one-time token that it last gave for that session and url combination (this could probably be stored in a temporary session table). When the AJAX request occurs, the backend verifies that the URL, session and token all match. The token is thus invalid for any different URL (trying to change a different model via spoofed request), and any different session. If you want to really make it difficult, you can also return a new token with the request callback, making it one-time use only.

Comment: @Aaron D: You are right, on the server side you need to keep track of the token in a session object, which 'lives' as long as the user is logged in. Changng the token every time makes it difficult to implement.

Comment: hey Matt, thanks for your detailed post. 
i've implemented this, complete with keeping track of token cache on the server and admin page that lets' me see / clear tokens. i also went a step further to add a url hash "salt" to the token and later compare that to urlReferrer. this helps a little but it's still fairly easy to circumvent.. does require a little knowledge or trial and failiure during which i will hopefully be able to spot the errors..

Comment: what i mean by "easy to circumvent" is that in the end that token is used to establish access level, but the token can be copied and used from other views since http headers are so easy to override. almost ready to admit defeat with this approach. I am looking into httpOnly cookie https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: @Sonic Soul: You are welcome. Of course, you should combine this with windows authentication+authorization at the server and not rely on the token alone. And yes, another way to pass along the token is httpOnly as described as a different way to achieve this.

Comment: yeah, authentication is taken care of so the risk is just with user using his own token from another view. Also I think I may be able to leverage the mvc anti forgery framework to avoid having to manage my own tokens, since in the end all i care about is verifying that urlReferrer is not tampered with.. will post my progress, thanks and appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

So this is going to be one of those "you're doing it wrong" answers that I don't like, and so I apologize up front.  In any case, from the question and comments, I'm going to propose you approach the problem differently.  Instead of thinking about where did the request come from, think about what is the request trying to do.  You need to determine if the user can do that.

My guess as to why this is hard in your case is I think you have made your api interface too generic.  From your example api "api/common/update" I'm guessing you have a generic update api that can update anything, and you want to protect updating data X from a page that is only supposed to access data Y.  If I'm off base there then ignore me. :)

So my answer would be: don't do that. Change your api around so it starts with the data you want to work with: api/dataX api/dataY.  Then use user roles to protect those api methods appropriately.  Behind the scenes you can still have a common update routine if you like that and it works for you, but keep the api interface more concrete.

If you really don't want to have an api for each table, and if its appropriate for you situation, perhaps you can at least have an api for protected/admin tables and a separate api for the standard tables.  A lot of "if"s, but maybe this would work for your situation.

In addition, if your user can update some dataX but not other dataX, then you will have to do some sort of checking against your data, ideally against some root object and whether your user is authorized to see/use that root object.

So to summarize, avoid an overly generic api interface.  By being more concrete you can use the existing security tools to help you.

And good luck!

Comment: you're right in your assumptions, however this approach is what I am trying to avoid. 
I already have separate controller for admin and such, so that's no problem. However I do have a generic update method which I am hoping to keep because like i said my schema has 100's of tables so it would be a huge pain to model controllers after that. 

In some tables i've implemented row level authorization which can safely bypass controller level auth, but again i wouldn't want to do this on 100's of tables because it would be a nightmare to administer

Comment: basically I am looking for a definite answer on if what i am trying to do is possible or not possible. Seems that it is not possible but I can't say that with 100% confidence